# Input Auto-Generated Figures Captions

Tags: captions, external-files, matlab

I'm trying to include an Matlab-auto-generated figure-caption tex-file using

```
\caption{\input{Spectrogram-2011-09-28-S003.title.tex}}
```

but if fails with error

```
ERROR: Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
```

I've tried all kinds of syntactic variants. How to solve this?

Comment: `try \caption{\protect\input ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method is to `protect` the input command by using:

```
\caption{\protect\input{figure.caption.tex}}
```

Comment: Yes, you need `.tex` at the end if there is another dot in the file name, which is the case here. Otherwise an extension `.caption` is used.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, I was not aware of that. Thanks, will modify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`\caption{<caption>}` will try to write the `<caption>` to an auxiliary file and LaTeX's `\input` isn't fully expandable. This alone will cause an error. You should store the content of the `Spectrogram-2011-09-28-S003.title.tex` file first into a macro. The `catchfile` package can be used for this.

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
% ...

\CatchFileDef{\matlabcaption}{Spectrogram-2011-09-28-S003.title.tex}{}%
\caption{\matlabcaption}
```